# request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Compile Error: Cannot declare class

Tags: php, symfony

I use the following two classes with the same name.

/src/AppBundle/Qrcode.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Qrcode;

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

class Qrcode
{
```

And

/vendor/Endroid/.../Qrcode.php

```
namespace Endroid\QrCode;

use Endroid\QrCode\Exceptions\DataDoesntExistsException;
use Endroid\QrCode\Exceptions\VersionTooLargeException;
use Endroid\QrCode\Exceptions\ImageSizeTooLargeException;
use Endroid\QrCode\Exceptions\ImageFunctionUnknownException;
use ReflectionFunction;

class QrCode
{
```

on the dev it works well but not on the prod one as I receive the following error message:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>       Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error:
>       Cannot declare class AppBundle\Qrcode because the name is
>       already in use" at .../src/AppBundle/Qrcode.php line 8.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. The namespaces are different and
It works on the dev part...
Thanks

Comment: Write 
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode as EndroidQr

Comment: The error is clear, you are declared a `QrCode` class twice

Comment: Yes but the namespaces are made for that, no ?

Comment: @Laurent: You need to differentiate class with alias because QrCode Class  is loaded twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate class with alias because `QrCode` Class  is loaded twice.

In, `/src/AppBundle/Qrcode.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Qrcode;

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode as EndroidQr // assign alias here to differnciate class
```

after this, `new EndroidQr();` would instantiate a `Endroid\QrCode\QrCode` Class

**Note**:-  If you want to load one class in a file who has same class name then you need to assign alias.

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Yes I'll try this, but I was thinking that namespaces were made for giving the ability os using same classe names within dirrent spaces. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Laurent: You are correct. But what happening here is you have used use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode; which have QrCode at last. If you cannot assign alias to it. then it will not allow you to re declare class with same name. Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: AppBundle\Qrcode\QrCode and Endroid\QrCode\QrCode are two different classes with the same name.  But with namespace you can differentiate it. If you want to load one class in a file who has same class name then you need to assign alias.

Comment: No not yet... it tries to call a function defined in EndroidQrCode from my class... Still "fighting" ;-)

Comment: Ok I understand now why it breaks, because symfony is making a big compilation file of all php... But this gives useless of namespaces, no ?

Comment: No. You are still confused. use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode means QrCode class  of /vendor/Endroid/.../Qrcode.php is loaded. So you cannot declare QrCode class again in the same file. If you want to declare class with same name then you need to assign alias.

Comment: Yes but the classes have their own files, it's just that symfony compiles everything so at the end i'ts in the same file. That's why it was working on dev (using separate files) on not on prod (using one file)... So I've renamed my class to simplify. Thanks a lot for your time, help and explanations

Comment: You are welcome :-) If your issue is resolved then accept the answer so future visitors can find it as useful.

Comment: By accepting, I think you mean clicking on the arrow to the top... I don't have enough "reputation" to do this, the site refuses. But thanks indeed

Comment: Did ! I didn't know about this ;-)